# Retrieve list of visible items in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I keep a list of current alarms and events in a basic datagrid, the user can scroll through the list. The user can select one item and acknowledge that specific alarm. This works.

The user should also be aloud to acknowledge all visible items. This is where im stuck. **Is it possible to retrieve a list of currentcollectionshown from a datagrid?**

Part of XAML

```
<Grid Background="DarkGray">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Content="Ack visible" Command="{Binding AcknowledgeVisibleCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Ack selected" Command="{Binding AcknowledgeSelectedCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>    
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AlarmAndEventList}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAlarmItem}" Background="DarkGray" IsReadOnly="True">
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Part of ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<AlarmItem> AlarmAndEventList { get { return  _AlarmAndEventList; } }

    private void AcknowledgeVisible()
    {
        //Do something with a list of visible items in datagrid
    }

    private void AcknowledgeSelected()
    {
        if (SelectedAlarmItem != null)
        {
            AlarmAndEventInstance.updateAlarmItem(SelectedAlarmItem);
        }


    }
```

Also, I want to run the single acknowledge command if the user double clicks an item. What is the "MVVM Way" of responding to a double click on a datagrid?

Comment: How are you hiding the item in data grid (or through bind collection)?

Comment: When you say 'visible' items, do you mean those that are not filtered out, or do you mean those that are currently in the viewable space on the UI.  The first is under your own control of course, so I assume you mean the latter, but wanted to check ...

Comment: Yes I mean the items which are currently visible on the UI User have to scroll to see more items.

Comment: It is possible to bind to the "SelectedItem" property. It should be possible to "CurrentlyVisibleItems"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To observe the currently visible items in a `DataGrid` I have written the following attached-property:

```
public class DataGridExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObserveVisiblePersonsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ObserveVisiblePersons", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnObserveVisiblePersonsChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisiblePersonsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "VisiblePersons", typeof(List<Person>), typeof(DataGridExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty SenderDataGridProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SenderDataGrid", typeof(DataGrid), typeof(DataGridExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataGrid)));

    private static void OnObserveVisiblePersonsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid == null)
            return;
        dataGrid.Loaded += DataGridLoaded;
    }

    private static void DataGridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid) sender;
        dataGrid.Loaded -= DataGridLoaded;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChildren<ScrollViewer>(dataGrid).FirstOrDefault();
        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
            SetSenderDataGrid(scrollViewer, dataGrid);
            scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += ScrollViewerOnScrollChanged;
        }
    }

    public static void SetObserveVisiblePersons(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ObserveVisiblePersonsProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetObserveVisiblePersons(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(ObserveVisiblePersonsProperty);
    }

    private static void SetSenderDataGrid(DependencyObject element, DataGrid value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SenderDataGridProperty, value);
    }

    private static DataGrid GetSenderDataGrid(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (DataGrid) element.GetValue(SenderDataGridProperty);
    }

    private static void ScrollViewerOnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer == null)
            return;

        ScrollBar verticalScrollBar =
            FindChildren<ScrollBar>(scrollViewer).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical);
        if (verticalScrollBar != null)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = GetSenderDataGrid(scrollViewer);

            int totalCount = dataGrid.Items.Count;
            int firstVisible = (int) verticalScrollBar.Value;
            int lastVisible = (int) (firstVisible + totalCount - verticalScrollBar.Maximum);

            List<Person> visiblePersons = new List<Person>();
            for (int i = firstVisible; i <= lastVisible; i++)
            {
                visiblePersons.Add((Person) dataGrid.Items[i]);
            }
            SetVisiblePersons(dataGrid, visiblePersons);
        }
    }

    public static void SetVisiblePersons(DependencyObject element, List<Person> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(VisiblePersonsProperty, value);
    }

    public static List<Person> GetVisiblePersons(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (List<Person>) element.GetValue(VisiblePersonsProperty);
    }

    private static IList<T> FindChildren<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        List<T> retval = new List<T>();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); counter++)
        {
            FrameworkElement toadd = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, counter) as FrameworkElement;
            if (toadd != null)
            {
                T correctlyTyped = toadd as T;
                if (correctlyTyped != null)
                {
                    retval.Add(correctlyTyped);
                }
                else
                {
                    retval.AddRange(FindChildren<T>(toadd));
                }
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

And in the xaml in the definition of your `DataGrid` you have to write the following:

```
nameSpaceOfAttachedProperty:DataGridExtensions.ObserveVisiblePersons="True"
nameSpaceOfAttachedProperty:DataGridExtensions.VisiblePersons="{Binding VisiblePersons, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

And in your ViewModel you will have a property like:

```
private List<Person> visiblePersons;
public List<Person> VisiblePersons
{
    get { return visiblePersons; }
    set
    {
        visiblePersons = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And every time you scroll the VisiblePersons will be updated.

In your case you have to changed the type of the List inside the attached-propertay to match your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use `MyDataGrid.Items` collection to filter out.
2. You can also apply filtering in your MyDataGrid. But don't show filtered items. [How to filter DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I am currently looking for something to bind to a property in my viewmodel which can hold the current visible items in the datagridview. Since the collection is larger than the view, a scrollbar is present. Let say there is 20 items in the collection the datagridview is only showing 4 of them, i want to bind a property to the four items currently shown/visible to the user.

Comment: @Snovva1 rest 16 are present but needs scrolling to get viewed ?